# How to set request headers using typed-rest-client?

Tags: typescript, typed-rest-client

I want to add some headers to a request using typed-rest-client in Typescript.

I didn't find any documentation so I looked a bit at typed-rest-client source code but I didn't manage to fully understand how it works.

I've tried the following code, but I get the error: "ReferenceError: Headers is not defined". So I don't think I have to create an instance of the class Headers.

```
import * as restm from 'typed-rest-client';
...
var restc: restm.RestClient = new restm.RestClient(
  'api.openweathermap.org',
  'https://api.openweathermap.org',
);
var temperaturePath = '/data/2.5/weather';
var apiKey = 'xxx';
var headrs = new Headers();
headrs.append('appid', apiKey);
headrs.append('q', location);
headrs.append('units', 'metric');
var requestOptions = {
  additionalHeaders: headrs
};
const response = restc.get(temperaturePath, requestOptions);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `IRequestOptions` which is stated below.

```
export interface IRequestOptions {
    // defaults to application/json
    // common versioning is application/json;version=2.1
    acceptHeader?: string,
    // since accept is defaulted, set additional headers if needed
    additionalHeaders?: ifm.IHeaders,

    responseProcessor?: Function,
    //Dates aren't automatically deserialized by JSON, this adds a date reviver to ensure they aren't just left as strings
    deserializeDates?: boolean
}
```

And `IHeaders`

```
export interface IHeaders { [key: string]: any };
```

Sample code:

```
let options: IRequestOptions = {additionalHeaders: {'key' : 'value' }};
let rest: rm.RestClient = new rm.RestClient(param1, param2, param3, options);
...
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to add an extra header to an existing set of options.   For example, adding a cookie that is gotten back from the first request.  Do I have to repeat the whole list of headers?